# Is a graph still considered cylic if its only in one direction?

Tags: graph, theory

I know a graph is considered cylic if it has at least one cycle. However, I can't seem to find an answer to the question if its only cylic in one direction. This graph is cylic from

> (A -> C -> B -> E)

However this doesn't work in the opposite direction

> (E -> B -> C -/> A)

So is this graph still considered cylic? I believe it would be, but I just can't find confirmation of this.

[image: Graph in Question]

Comment: There are 4 cycles maybe: **1. E->A->C->B->E**, **2. A->C->B->A**, **3. E->B->E** and **4. C->B->C**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a directed graph is cyclic if and only if it contains at least one directed cycle. A (simple) directed cycle is a list of arcs such that (1) each vertex is the head of at most one arc in the list (2) the head of each arc in the list is the tail of the next arc in the list, wrapping around to the beginning if it's at the end. You can chase references from Wikipedia if you won't take it on my authority as a CS PhD specialized in graph algorithms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory).